# How do I test the performance of a video in a web browser?

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm working on an app where the videos should load and start playing as fast as possible without much latency in a browser. The video duration will not be more than 3 minutes. We have a size restriction of 300 MB as well.

I'm looking at 3 options

1. AWS Media Streaming with CloudFront
2. Cloudflare Video Streaming
3. Cloudinary

Should I only test the Video URL speed or should it be coupled with the player used on the web page?

I'm a little confused about how to compare and test the performance of the videos in a web page from the 3 options.

Could someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see speed and responsiveness of the videos from the 3 different locations - I built a tool that can give you some benchmarks:
https://dougsillars.github.io/StreamOrNot/

It will give you startup time, stalls etc. I would recommend using devTools to throttle the network to different speeds to see how the three providers compare on slower networks. (I'd love to see your results too!)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to think about how your users will use the service and try to align your testing.

For example if they will only ever use a single device type, browser and player then you can concentrate on that combination. If not you will likely want to test with a representative mix of devices, players and browsers.

Some things to be aware of:

- videos will be cached typically on your device or application so you will likely want to clear the cache between tests, if you want to see performance when not cached.
- CDN (Contenting Delivery Networks like Cloudfront) often work by storing a video at the 'edge' after it is first accessed. This means that the first access can be slower than subsequent access. The content will usually have an expiry time if it is not accessed again at the edge, also.
- There are multiple options with most of these services to help reduce latency, often balancing speed against quality - for example you could have a very low bit rate stream to allow fast startup and then step up through the ABR bit rates as you progress (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZDSFR3WQIU). You may want to define some common criteria to ensure a level playing field for your tests.

And finally, different CDN's can be stronger in different geographical regions, and to complicate things further, at different times depending on network load. Some large services use a multi CDN approach to balance performance and cost at any given time.